# Carrierwave not saving the file on disk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

everyone. Please, help me with carrierwave and Rails 4.

Model:

```
class MediaItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :media_item, MediaItemUploader
end
```

Schema:

```
create_table "media_items", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "file"
  t.text     "description", default: "", null: false
  t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
end
```

Uploader:

```
class MediaItemUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
    "public/"
  end
```

Controller:

```
class MediaItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @media_item = MediaItem.new(media_item_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @media_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @media_item, notice: 'Media item was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
```

Form:

```
= form_for @media_item, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :description
    = f.text_field :description
  .field
    = f.label :file
    = f.file_field :file
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

The problem is that uploaded file does not appear in specified dir and "media_item.media_item_url" return empty string in a view. However, it save the recore into db:

```
select file, description from media_items;
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xba672374>|wetw
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake.

Instead

```
mount_uploader :media_item, MediaItemUploader
```

it must be

```
mount_uploader :file, MediaItemUploader
```

as "file" is a field name in db, not "media_item"